# How many items can be queued in the waitqueu in linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device

I want to know what is maximum size of  waitqueue. How to know upper limit of waitqueue

regards
Sobin

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/wait.h#L39)  , the waitqueue is just a task list, so there is not max size:

```
struct __wait_queue_head {
        spinlock_t              lock;
        struct list_head        task_list;
};
typedef struct __wait_queue_head wait_queue_head_t;
```